# How do I make the logo icons to appear on the right side of my footer?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to link social media sites with the corresponding logo, no problem there. The problem occurs when I try to put the li items to the right of the footer.

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer-wrapper">
    <ul><a href="">HOME</a></ul>

    <div class="footer-link-wrapper">
      <ul><a href="">ABOUT</a></ul>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-link-wrapper">
      <ul><a href="">CATCH UP</a></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-media-links">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
            <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/sott_brand/?hl=en">
            <ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/sott_brand/_saved/">
            <ion-icon name="logo-pinterest"></ion-icon>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</footer>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS to float the items to the right side of your footer.

```
.footer-media-links {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.footer-media-links ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: flex-end; /* pushes the content to right side */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your HTML and added a whole new CSS... Hopefully your don't mind :)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .column #icons
  {
      float:right;
  }

  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }

  li
  {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline;
      margin: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Footer</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CATCH UP</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div id="icons">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
                            <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/sott_brand/?hl=en">
                            <ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/sott_brand/_saved/">
                            <ion-icon name="logo-pinterest"></ion-icon>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
   </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Have a great day!